# catkin_make error when using vrpn_client_ros

Tags: ros, catkin-make, optitrack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I want to connect Optitrack and ROS together, using the package vrpn_client_ros.
Now, I'm using ubuntu14.04 installed ros indigo. I found the package from    http://wiki.ros.org/vrpn_client_ros    and git clone the code form     https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/vrpn_client_ros.git    into my folder ~/catkin_ws/src. but when I run

```
catkin_make
```

,

it came to errors like ths:

```
> CMake Error at
> vrpn_client_ros/CMakeLists.txt:5
> (find_package):   By not providing
> "FindVRPN.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
> this project has   asked CMake to find
> a package configuration file provided
> by "VRPN", but   CMake did not find
> one.
>
>   Could not find a package
> configuration file provided by "VRPN"
> with any of   the following names:
>
>     VRPNConfig.cmake
>     vrpn-config.cmake
>
>   Add the installation prefix of
> "VRPN" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set  
> "VRPN_DIR" to a directory containing
> one of the above files.  If "VRPN"  
> provides a separate development
> package or SDK, be sure it has been  
> installed.
>
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also
> "/home/sen/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". See also
> "/home/sen/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
> Invoking "cmake" failed
```

Why this happen? What should I do next? I will appreciate if you could help. Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227267/catkin_make-error-when-using-vrpn_client_ros/) by [Shusen](https://answers.ros.org/users/26018/shusen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2016-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are missing the vrpn dependency for the package.

You could install all dependencies for your workspace via rosdep (`rosdep install --from-paths .`)

Or you could just install debians, which will pull in dependencies automatically (`sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-vrpn-client-ros`). Is there a reason you want to run from source?

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2016-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shusen](https://answers.ros.org/users/26018/shusen/) on 2016-02-22**:
Thanks a lot! It works. I want to connect Optitrack and ROS together, and then connect to pixhawk, then fly quadrotor indoors, I don't know what to do next. Can you give me some advice?

**Comment by [UbuntuROs](https://answers.ros.org/users/30914/ubunturos/) on 2017-06-26**:
I have kind of similar problem I tried to run catkin_make after cloning to catkin_ws and exporting it but I received this error

> Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/kidus/catkin_ws/build"

**Comment by [jason](https://answers.ros.org/users/29292/jason/) on 2017-08-28**:
Hi Paul, I am using ros lunar and met this error. I copied the source package into my workspace and catkin_make, the same error occurs. I tried to install the  VRPNConfig.cmake vrpn-config.cmake related package/library, but failed. DO you have any idea to solve this?